IllegalStateException in Integration Tests in Spring Boot
I'm encountering an IllegalStateException when running integration tests for my Spring Boot application. The error seems related to Flyway attempting to connect to PostgreSQL during the tests, even though I have disabled Flyway in the application-test.properties file.
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(classes = SampleApplication.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT) 
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) 
public abstract class AbstractSpringIntegrationTest{      
@LocalServerPort     
public int port;  
}

public class SampleControllerTest extends AbstractSpringIntegrationTest {     
@MockBean     
private SampleService sampleService;      
@Autowired     
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;      
@Test     
void testMethodSuccess() {       ......     }

Below is my test/resources/application-test.properties which i have created specific to testcases.
# Disable Flyway for tests
spring.flyway.enabled=false

while running the testcase i got the below error message
SampleControllerTest > testMethodSuccess() FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:180
        Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException at JdbcUtils.java:60
            Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException at ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:346
                Caused by: java.net.ConnectException at Net.java:-2

what am i missing here?
Even with Flyway disabled in application-test.properties, it seems like Flyway is still trying to perform migrations and connect to PostgreSQL, leading to a ConnectException.
What I Have Tried:

Verified that spring.flyway.enabled=false is correctly set.

Checked if there are any other configurations that might be triggering Flyway or PostgreSQL connections during tests.


How can I resolve this issue so that my integration tests run without trying to connect to PostgreSQL and without Flyway attempting to perform migrations?

This question is similar to: How to disable flyway in a particular Spring profile?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
